# How to fetch * records from a table which are not present in other two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to fetch all records with all columns of a table, Records which are not in the other 2 tables. Please help.

I have tried below query, it is working fine for comparing one column. But I want to compare 5 columns.

```
select * from A 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(select * from B b where b.id=a.id) AND
NOT EXISTS
(select * from C c where c.id=a.id)
```

Comment: google how to do a Left Join. try it, and if you make mistakes, post your code.

Comment: Please share us what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Karan plz see the updated question.

Comment: Your query seems correct. You should be getting desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general solution might look like:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.t2_id) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table3 t3 WHERE t3.id = t1.t3_id);
```

This assumes that you want to target `table1` for records, ensuring that no matches can found in `table2` and `table3`.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this approach:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 AS t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2
        ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
    LEFT JOIN table3 AS t3
        ON t1.id = t3.t1_id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
      AND t3.id IS NULL;
```

While this might be a bit less intuitive than using sub queries I think odds of making mistakes with aliases are less likely as in the example below, which happens more often than you might expect:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE id = id) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table3 WHERE id = id);
```

To your question about checks on 5 columns, that can still be done using either of these methods by adding conditions either in the left joins or in the where clause of each sub query.